# How to rotate a Texture Gradient with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, vector-mapping

I have a plane, subdivided a couple of times and instanced cones onto the points with Geometry Nodes. The scale is set by a (linear) gradient texture along the X-axis.

I was able to translate the texture, but I cannot figure out how to rotate it to make it go along the Y-axis or diagonally or in between. The vector rotate node doesn't seem to affect it in any way.

How can I rotate the Texture Gradient with Geometry Nodes?

EDIT: Is there maybe an easier way to visualize the gradient?

[image: Field of cones growing larger along the X-axis made with Geometry nodes.]

[image: Geometry Nodes setup, Cone instanced on points, Gradient texture into Colorramp into Scale of instances]

Comment: Try the Vector-Math-Node `Rotate Vector`...

Comment: @quellenform I tried that, I put it right after the Gradient Texture. I got a different set-up with a sphere, but no matter what I do, the gradient goes from left-to-right and I just can't get it to go vertical in this case.

Please, try it for yourself with my file: [link](https://bit.ly/3OfVGJq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Gradient > Linear* texture, left to itself, simply returns the X of the texture-space it's been given.

By default, in GN, its texture-space is 'Object'. That is, coordinates measured in Blender Units, 0 at the object-origin, down the object's own X, Y and Z axes.

In order to rotate the texture, you give it a rotated texture-space. That means you have to make the default explicit, so you can manipulate it. *Position* measures object-space:

[image]

.. so that's one way to rotate the texture:

[image]